# python 2.7 best xlsx read/write

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best suggested xlsx file read/write library for Python 2.7?

Comment: try openpyxl only if its an xlsx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) package, this is the one I use for reading/formating excel spreadsheets (easiest way I find), beginning with:

```
 my_sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('my_sheet', encoding_override="utf-8")
```

you can also use [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt), opening your spreadsheet like an object and modify it :

```
import xlwt

test = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = test.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')

sheet.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula('B1+A2'), style0)

test.save('test.xls')
```

Comment: Does it also used for writing an excel file?

Comment: For writing it is better to use xlwt, I edit it, sorry.